# Handling saving multiple django model forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing an administration dashboard for some of our internal staff, and I have an instance where I need to save two of the same model form instances via the same logic.

The first instance will save correctly, however the second instance never saves.

I've been trying to work out what causes this issue for about an hour, as no error message is returned.

The form returns as expected, however it is missing both of the forms content when it returns from Django. I am only sending the form that the user selects to submit via ajax, so this is not a surprise

```
def update_client_details(request, client_id, context=None):

    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User.objects.get(pk=client_id)
        if AdviserQueue.objects.filter(email=user.email, adviser=request.user).exists():

            first_instance = ConciergeLeadCapture.objects.get(user=user, named_user=True)
            first_form = ConciergeLeadCaptureForm(request.POST, instance=first_instance, prefix='first_client')
            if first_form.has_changed() and first_form.is_valid():
                first_form.save()
            context['lead_capture_first'] = first_form

            second_instance = ConciergeLeadCapture.objects.get(user=user, named_user=False)
            second_form = ConciergeLeadCaptureForm(request.POST, instance=second_instance, prefix='second_client')
            if second_form.has_changed() and second_form.is_valid():
                second_form.save()
            context['lead_capture_second'] = second_form

            return render(request, 'concierge/adviser/client_dashboard_lead_capture_form.html', context)
```

Comment: Add some print/log statements to your code to see what the problem is: is the post data what you expect? What is the value of `second_form.has_changed() and `second_form.is_valid()`.

Comment: Post data is as expected, has_changed is True, and is_valid is false, but it should be true :s

Comment: So, put `{{ lead_capture_second.errors}}` in your template and find out why it's not valid.

Comment: the error is  "This field is required." However, every field returns with data in it, and the data appears in request.POST

Comment: Worked it out >.< A boolean field was hidden, which was marked as required. I've excluded it from the form and it's all working now :)